# codomain fibration of a topos is a stack

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In fact, the condition can be weakened into these versions as in the forum post:

https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/560/codomain-stacks/

Is there any proof of this fact (or some proofs that can be easily modified into a proof of this)?

I would be happy if someone can directly refer to a textbook. But if there is not any, many thanks for writing out a proof or a sketch!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the stack condition for coproducts is extensivity, and the stack condition for (regular) epimorphisms is Barr-exactness, more or less. But if you want details you should state your definitions.

Comment: @Y.X. Would you be interested in seing a proof which uses the internal dependently typed language of a topos (i.e. $\Sigma$-types, disjoint coproducts indexed by external sets and dependent effective quotient types)?

Comment: @Nico Yes, definitely. Honestly, I am only rather familiar with internal logic in a topos, but is trying to learn more about type aspects. I believe that would be helpful.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for your hints! And the definition I am thinking about is as in this one. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512.pdf

Comment: @Y.X. I have given my best. The best way to read it is to pretend that the category $\mathscr S$ is actually a category of (intiuitionistic) sets and to draw a few pictures.

Comment: @Y.X. If you want to have a hint how the categorical proof looks like, then you need to remember that the interpretation of the $\Sigma$-type is "post-composition with the display map" and the interpretation of quotient types are coequalizers.

Comment: @Y.X. You also asked for a reference, and I just happen to stumble over on. Lemma B1.5.10 in Johnstone's "Sketches of an Elephant" shows that the self-indexing is a stack in the coherent topology already when the base category is a pretopos.

Comment: @Nico Oh yes. I find it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us fix an elementary topos $\mathscr S$. We start with a type $\vdash J:Type$ in the empty context and a bunch of types $j:J\vdash I_\alpha(j) : Type$ above $J$. This is in essence the same thing as an object $().J$ in the base category $\mathscr S$ plus a bunch of maps $p_\alpha: ().J.I_\alpha \to ().J$ into that object. The $p_\alpha$ are the display maps of the dependent types $I_\alpha$. The best exposition of the precise categorical semantic I am aware of is Martin Hofmann's text *On the interpretation of type theory in locally cartesian closed categories*. I will take all that for granted and just move on (because it is to much for a stackexchange post).

I denote the self-indexing $\partial_1:\mathscr S^\mathbf 2\to \mathscr S$ by $\mathbb S$. Let us define a category $Desc((I_\alpha)_\alpha,\mathbb S)$ of descent data. An object in the category of descent data consists of a family of dependent types$$j:J,i:I_\alpha(j)\vdash X_\alpha(j,i):Type$$
together with isomorphisms $$j:J,i_1:I_\alpha(j),i_2:I_\beta(j)\vdash \theta_{\alpha \beta}(j,i_1,i_2):X_\alpha(j,i_1)\to X_\beta(j,i_2)$$
which satisfy the cocycle condition. The cocycle condition states that for each triple $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of indices we have that the following subsingelton type is inhabited (our equality is extensional).
$$j:J,i_1:I_\alpha(j),i_2:I_\beta(j),i_3:I_\gamma(j)\vdash \theta_{\beta\gamma}(j,i_2,i_3)\circ\theta_{\alpha \beta}(j,i_1,i_2)=\theta_{\alpha\gamma}(j,i_1,i_3)$$

A morphism of descent data $(X_\alpha, \theta_{\alpha\beta})\to (X'_\alpha,\theta'_{\alpha\beta})$ consists of terms $j:J,i:I_\alpha(j)\vdash
f_\alpha(j,i):X_\alpha(j,i)\to X'_\alpha(j,i)$ which are compatible with the structure isomorphisms. There is a restriction functor $$Fib_\mathscr S(().J,\mathbb S)\to Desc((I_\alpha)_\alpha,\mathbb S)$$
where $Fib_\mathscr S(().J,\mathbb S)$ is the category of types $j:J\vdash X(j):Type$ depending on $().J$. The restriction functor just weakens along the display maps, the structure isomorphisms are identities. We say that the codomain fibration satisfies descent with respect to the family $(I_\alpha)_\alpha$ of sets depending on $().J$ when the functor is fully faithful. It satisfies effective descent when the functor is an equivalence.

I will now show that $\mathbb S$ is a prestack in the coherent topology. The covers consists of finite families of maps which are jointly epi. We may thus assume that the $\alpha$ range over an external finite set and that the display maps cover $().J$. In the internal language this means that we may assume that $$\forall j:J.\bigvee_\alpha (\exists i:I_\alpha(j))$$
is valid, i.e. that from the internal perspective at least one of the $I_\alpha(j)$ is always inhabited. So assume we have two maps $j:J\vdash f(j),g(j): X(j)\to Y(j)$ which yield the same morphisms of descent data after we restricted them. This means that the following subsingelton type is inhabited for each $\alpha$. $$j:J,i:I_\alpha(j)\vdash f(j) = g(j)$$ In other words it holds that $\forall j:J.\forall i:I_\alpha(j).f(j) = g(j)$ is true for each $\alpha$. Now combining this with $\forall j:J.\bigvee_\alpha (\exists i:I_\alpha (j))$ and a bit of intuitionistic logic shows us that $\forall j:J.f(j) = g(j)$ is also valid. In other words we have show that the restriction functor to descent data is faithful. To show that it is full, assume we start with two dependent types $j:J\vdash X(j),Y(j):Type$. Assume that we have terms $j:J,i:I_\alpha(j)\vdash f_\alpha(i,j) : X(j) \to Y(j)$ which together yield a morphism of descent data. That the $f_\alpha$ are a morphism of descent data means that the following holds for each tuple $\alpha\beta$ of external indices. $$\forall j:J.\forall i_1:I_\alpha(j).\forall i_2:I_\beta(j). f_\alpha(j,i_1) = f_\beta(j,i_2)$$
Using again that internally for each $j$ at least one $I_\alpha(j)$ is inhabited, we can derive that the following is valid internally.
$$\forall j:J.\forall x:X(j).\exists ! y:Y(j). \bigvee_\alpha (\exists i:I_\alpha(j) \wedge y = f_\alpha(j,i)(x))$$
When we write $\varphi(j,x,y)$ for the formula appearing after the $\exists !$-quantifier, then we may use the $\iota$-operator of definite description to get the term which we like. (This is a bit of a cheat, since showing that the $\iota$-operator of definite description has a sound semantic is essentially the same thing as showing that $\mathbb S$ is a prestack, but since it is often part of type theory, I will freely use it). We can judge that $$j:J,x:X(j) \vdash \iota y.\varphi(j,x,y) :  Y(j) $$ and the function which we are looking for is of course $$j:J\vdash \lambda x.(\iota y.\varphi(j,x,y)):X(j)\to Y(j)$$
We have shown that the functor into descent data is full. Finally, let us check that $(I_\alpha)_\alpha$ is an effective family of dependent types (i.e. that the functor into descent data is essentially surjective on objects). For that we will need effective quotient types and disjoint coproducts. We start with an object $(X_\alpha,\theta_{\alpha\beta})$ in the category of descent data. We like to find a dependent type $j:J\vdash X(j):Type$ which restricts up to an isomorphism to our descent data. The dependent type $X$ will be a quotient of the following type.$$j:J\vdash \bigsqcup_\alpha \sum_{i:I_\alpha(j)}X_\alpha(j,i)$$
Let us for a second write $j:J\vdash Y(j)$ for that type. To get a quotient type we need to produce an internal equivalence relation
$$j:J\vdash R(j): Y(j)\times Y(j) \to Prop$$
I am using the subobject classifier $Prop$ only to simplify the notation, it is not really necessary for the proof! The idea is of course to identify all the fibers $X_\alpha(j,i)$ where $j$ is fixed and $\alpha$ and $i$ vary. So the relation we need is the following one. \begin{align}j:J,y_1:\bigsqcup_\alpha \sum_{i:I_\alpha(j)}X_\alpha(j,i), y_2:\bigsqcup_\alpha \sum_{i:I_\alpha(j)}X_\alpha(j,i) \vdash \\ \bigvee_{\alpha \beta} \exists i_1:I_\alpha(j).\exists i_2: I_\beta(j).\exists x_1:X_\alpha(j,i_1).\exists x_2:X_\beta(j,i_2). \\(y_1 = inc_\alpha (i_1,x_1)\wedge y_2 = inc_\beta (i_2,x_2) \wedge \theta_{\alpha\beta}(j,i_1,i_2)(x_1)= x_2) : Prop\end{align}
I hope there is no typo in the formula. Let me write $R(j,y_1,y_2)$ for it. The internal equivalence relation which we need is $\lambda (y_1,y_2).R(j,y_1,y_2): Y(j)\times Y(j)\to Prop$. It is reflexive the $\theta_{\alpha \alpha}$ are identities. It is transitive because of the cocycle condition and symmetric because the $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ are invertible. We may thus define $j:J\vdash X(j)$ as the dependent quotient $$j:J\vdash \left(\bigsqcup_\alpha \sum_{i:I_\alpha(j)} X_\alpha(i,j)\right)/R(j) : Type$$
The universal property of quotients then gives us comparison morphisms $$j:J,i:I_\alpha(j)\vdash q_\alpha(j,i): X(j)\to X_\alpha(i,j)$$
The remaining steps are checking that the comparison morphisms assemble into a morphism of descent data, and that they are bijective from the internal perspective (this implies that they are isomorphisms). For this we will need that the coproducts are disjoint and quotients are effective. I skip over the rest, because the answer is already long.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing it out and for the reference! I have a question: when taking the infinite coproduct, how do we know that this exists? (I am not aware of any assumption on cocompleteness).

Comment: @Y.X. Yes, I am only showing that the self-indexing is a stack for the coherent topology, which is generated by finite jointly epic families! but the same proof goes through for small Set-indexed families when the topos in cocomplete (relative to Set)

Comment: @Y.X. I believe I have written "coherent topology" somewhere :)

Comment: But in the link I referred to, I believe there is no assumption on cocompleteness. Does that mean this argument does not work for such cases? Say, in this nlab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+category , the coherent category is not assumed to be cocomplete. What would we do for such cases? Or is there any assumption I missed which implies cocompleteness?

Comment: I think if we only think of cocomplete categories. Say, $\mathsf{Top}$, then this argument you have written down is basically the same as https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512.pdf proposition 4.1.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the word "finite", you have already written that out. But do you agree that your argument is a type-theoretic rephrasing of the link I posted above (or is there anything to remark about something specific to type theory)? It is good to see that I can compare them in this way then.

Comment: @Y.X. in a coherent category the self indexing is not necessarily a stack. the proof of prop 4.1. follows exactly the same idea and mental image as the proof i have written down above! the difference is that you can work with actual points in Top, because Top is concrete. you can not do this in a topos, so you have to use tricks (i.e. generalized points/type theory). but the idea is still the same.

Comment: @Y.X. If you want a categorical proof then you have to translate the type theoretical one via the categorical semantic of type theory, or you have to try to repreat the same proof as in prop 4.1., but in a pointless style!

Comment: @Y.X. also the self-indexing of Top will probably not satisfy the stack condition even for covers consisting of a single quotient map $u: V \to U$, because Top is not exact. the proof in vistoli's notes only applies to covering families consisting of open embeddings.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering and for your remarks!